# Angular-cli - How to link font icons inside the assets folder to css

Tags: html, css, angular-cli

How do I link a font file inside the assets folder to my css?

My folder structure is as follows,

```
src
 - assets
 -- fontfile.eot
 - styles
 -- fontstyles
 --- fonts.scss
```

But when I link fontfile.eot in fonts.scss,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myicons';
  src:  url('../../assets/fontfile.eot');
}
```

It throws this error,

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '../../assets/fonts/fontfile.eot' in 'myproject/src/styles'

Same error comes when I move the fontfile inside the styles folder and link it.

```
src:  url('./fontfile.eot');
```

How do I link my font to my css?

I'm using angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, I'm thinking you don't need quotes in the URL:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'myicons';
  src:  url(../../assets/fontfile.eot) format("embedded-opentype");
}
```

Comment: Hi. Tried but still the same. :(
I think the font files are not getting added into the build folder.

Comment: I was going to say, don't .scss files compile into another folder? The path you use needs to be relative to that folder right?

Comment: It started working when I renamed fonts.scss to fonts.css. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I changed my angular-cli project over to scss to test the issue. Try changing your font path to "/content/fonts/fontfile.eot" in the .scss file, regardless of where the font is actually located.

"/content/fonts/fontfile.eot" is working for me in my project even when I have the fontfile at "src/assets/fontfile.eot" at compile time

Comment: "/content/fonts/fontfile.eot" doesn't give any errors. but the font icon is not showing on the ui. it's just showing a square.

Comment: I should also add, I can't see my font files in the dist folder when I build the app. "assets": [ "assets" ], this is all there is under assets in my angular-cli.json file if it helps.

Comment: Hm, that seems like it may be a font issue, my fonts are loading okay under the exact same circumstances. Are you getting any console errors saying the font could not be found or downloaded in the browser console? Also, make sure you install the font on your machine and check that it works.

Comment: Honestly, if I were you I would just move the font to src/content/fonts/fontfile.eot and call it day. Seems like webpack is doing some funny stuff under the hood with the scss pathing so better to not fight it.

Comment: remove url("") and just use "", I think that will do it for you